# Why i cant write and save html file in python?

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_data(url):
   headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.124 YaBrowser/22.9.3.886 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
   }

   r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   print(r.text)

   with open("projects.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(r.text)


get_data("https://music.yandex.ru/non-music/editorial/album/keep_calm")
```

I have an html information, but this code give errors. What i need to fix it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\BestParser\parser.py", line 17, in <module>
    get_data("https://music.yandex.ru/non-music/editorial/album/keep_calm")
  File "d:\python\BestParser\parser.py", line 14, in get_data
    file.write(r.text)
  File "D:\python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20bd' in position 20952: character maps to <undefined>
```

this are errors after launch programm
i new in python and i dont understand what i need to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback

Comment: Hello and welcome. For convienence please post the error message as well.

Comment: ok i wrote errors

Answer (score 1):

According to the traceback you provided, this is an issue related to your `projects.html` file encoding.

In order to use UTF-8 encoding, you should specify the `encoding` attribute for the `open()` function.

The code becomes:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_data(url):
   headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.124 YaBrowser/22.9.3.886 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
   }

   r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   print(r.text)

   # using utf-8 encoding here
   with open("projects.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(r.text)


get_data("https://music.yandex.ru/non-music/editorial/album/keep_calm")
```

Answer (score 1):

The character '\u20bd' "Ruble Sign" does not exist within the used encoding.

You could try specifying the encoding like the following:

```
with open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```